# How to escape or avoid cops

Tags: party-hard-2

After playing for a while I noticed that you either play ultra stealthy or you burn/explode the cops. There seems to be no other solution after trying a lot of things.
If you kill the witness, you avoid the cops, but what if you just can't get to the witness before the call?

Is there a simple way to avoid or escape the cops?

Comment: Now I can't speak for certain in party hard 2, but in the first you could keep on running around untill they give up

Comment: You have a limited amount of "running" in PH2